# Sanitize filters to decode a token

Tags: php, url

Original token in URL is:

> token=CfDJ8G5NDriMnx5OtZMpJNgIrfHJ49xUs8whC%2fCIpQ5ATCPw9uCComQ4YTuuHCMtq7IR8Ckji8v5iSBH%2f%2b9FsydakgGV4eVKqAgB0cRPsl8lbri6Z%2fqDIH70SIDHlR6hnmsC97f4LYq1O6w9Ug655luLKw57KUJWtLl%2f%2bfhSn4kh5yQEIctNpdZF8yMBNA%2feo0U%2f4Nla4Lz%2fZyPr1bn29lozG9ZPGoSh5GG0EYV%2bNumZ8BENpxrXZrSuhn%2f1%2fGFbyrquaA%3d%3d

But when I use:

```
$usertoken =  filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'token',FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
```

it returns:

> CfDJ8G5NDriMnx5OtZMpJNgIrfHJ49xUs8whC%2FCIpQ5ATCPw9uCComQ4YTuuHCMtq7IR8Ckji8v5iSBH%2F%2B9FsydakgGV4eVKqAgB0cRPsl8lbri6Z%2FqDIH70SIDHlR6hnmsC97f4LYq1O6w9Ug655luLKw57KUJWtLl%2F%2BfhSn4kh5yQEIctNpdZF8yMBNA%2Feo0U%2F4Nla4Lz%2FZyPr1bn29lozG9ZPGoSh5GG0EYV%2BNumZ8BENpxrXZrSuhn%2F1%2FGFbyrquaA%3D%3D

The problem is that, after every `%` character, the next few characters are in capital and not in the same format as in the URL token.

Comment: This is called [URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). They are normally written in uppercase and this change of case shouldn't affect the string you get when you decode the token with [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: URL encoding is NOT case sensitive and the conversion should bear no issues for you.  For example a slash `/` can be `%2f` OR `%2F` and is treated the same either way.  PHP just chooses to capitalize them, as capitalization is the "norm".

Comment: I have to pass this value to an api to verify a user.